# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network

I have quite a bit of experience with Python programming in general, but am very new to neural networks and deep learning. After having gone through Tech With Tim's Mega AI course, I decided to create a neural network on my own. It's very simple - it takes in a name and outputs 0 or 1 depending on its gender - 0 = male, 1 = female.

Here is my complete code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

encode_alphabet = '0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

data = pd.read_csv("names.csv")
X = data.drop(["OUT"], 1).values.tolist()
y = [int("".join([str(j) for j in i])) for i in data[["OUT"]].values.tolist()]

print(len(X))
print(len(y))

tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 12])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation="linear")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

model.fit(X, y, n_epoch=100, show_metric=True)

print(data)
```

And the names.csv file looks like this (first 5 lines):

```
L0  L1  L2  L3  L4  L5  L6  L7  L8  L9  L10 L11 OUT
0   0   0   0   0   0   15  12  9   22  5   18  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   7   5   15  18  7   5   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   1   18  18  25  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14  15  1   8   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  1   3   11  0
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

I have tried all sorts of model shapes but nothing seems to actually work.
I am very happy to give you guys more information if it's needed, but I am so new to all of this that an RTFM response really won't help at all.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explaining

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

It means your passed shape of `y` which is `(64,)` doesn't match the expected shape `(?, 1)`. To fix it, you only need to change the shape of `y` with:

```py
y = [[int("".join([str(j) for j in i]))] for i in data[["OUT"]].values.tolist()]
```

Or

```py
y = np.array([int("".join([str(j) for j in i])) for i in data[["OUT"]].values])
y = y.reshape(len(y), 1)
```

Comment: However, I'm getting an issue with learning. The binary_acc starts at about 42% on epoch 1 and plateaus in the range 42%-58% after leaving it on for 1000 epochs. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @macaquedev Sorry I don't.